# @DbLookup To Find Column

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to use an @DbLookup in my XPage app to pull data from a column in another application. The application filename that I'm wanting to call is: **aApplications\HCHPhoneBk.nsf** but I'm not sure how the structure for the @DbLookup would go. It's located on a server called: **DomApps01/Hendricks** and the column I am wanting to get is the 2nd one.

This is what I have now, and it's not working.

```
@DbLookup("";"HRH Phone Directory":"aApplications\HCHPhoneBk.nsf";"People";
```

Comment: Chad. In JavaScript the semicolons become commas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `@DbLookup()` is:

`@DbLookup([server, path], view, key, column)`

So in your case it should look something like this:

`@DbLookup(["DomApps01/Hendricks", "aApplications/HCHPhoneBk.nsf"], "People", key, 2)`

...where `"People"` is the view you want to search and `key` is the search value for the first column. If you just want to retrieve all the values in the second column without filtering it by the first column, use `@DbColumn` instead of `@DbLookup`; the syntax is identical, except you would omit the `key` parameter.

**P.S.** Note the use of `/` instead of `\` in the application path. `\` is an "escape character" in JavaScript, so in this syntax, `/` is preferred.

Comment: That was almost exactly what I was just typing as an answer. You beat me to it, Tim :-)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help Tim. Thanks to you as well Henrik!